# Itunes Smart Playlist - Sort by Descending Track Number

Tags: itunes, music, sort, smart-playlist

I want to create a smart playlist that will list an album by descending track number.

I have a singles album in which I would like to add new singles as time goes on but I want to listen to the new songs from that album first so play in reverse order. The track number is in chronological order i.e. 01, 02, 03 etc.

I want the playlist to play 09, 08, 07...in that order.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When creating the smart playlist, can you sort your tracks by 'most recently added'? That way, every time you add a new single, the most recent one will stay on top.

Comment: I am aware of that but I am looking for a way to sort the track number in descending order.